# EFCore5, using FromSqlRaw and [Owned] attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to take advantage of the EF Core "[Owned]" attribute when returning data from a stored procedure. My model is as follows...

```
[Keyless]
public class TestResult
{

    public TestResultManifest Manifest { get; set; } = new TestResultManifest();

    public Int32 TransportJobID { get; set; }

}

[Owned]
public class TestResultManifest
{

    public Int32 ManifestID { get; set; }

}
```

and this is implemented within my DbContext as follows...

```
public DbSet<TestResult> TestItems { get; set; }

public async Task<List<TestResult>> SelectTestItemsAsync()
{
    return await TestItems.FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE [dbo].[SelectTestItems]").ToListAsync();
}
```

It is my understanding [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) that when this is mapped directly to a physical table it would result in columns named "TransportJobID" and "Manifest_ManifestID", therefore I am using the following stored procedure to pull back the necessary data...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectTestItems]

as

    select Manifest_ManifestID = 3,
        TransportJobID = 22;

    return @@error;
```

Which as you would expect results in...

[image: the results from the stored procedure when executed within SSMS]

However, whenever I run this I get a NullReferenceException thrown deep inside Entity Framework...

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType, Nullable`1 navigationToTarget, Nullable`1 inverseNavigation, Nullable`1 setTargetAsPrincipal, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 required)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(TypeIdentity& targetEntityType, MemberIdentity navigation, Nullable`1 inverse, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(Type targetEntityType, MemberInfo navigationMember, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(Type targetEntityType, MemberInfo navigation, Boolean fromDataAnnotation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.CreateRelationships(IEnumerable`1 relationshipCandidates, IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverRelationships(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, IConventionContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.Process(IConventionEntityType entityType, String navigationName, MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.ProcessNavigationRemoved(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder sourceEntityTypeBuilder, IConventionEntityTypeBuilder targetEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationName, MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnNavigationRemoved(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder sourceEntityTypeBuilder, IConventionEntityTypeBuilder targetEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationName, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnNavigationRemovedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies, Boolean _)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor(ConventionSet conventions, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw[TEntity](DbSet`1 source, String sql, Object[] parameters)
```

I would expect this to work given that I am merely using (what I believe to be) standard functionality - at least I would have thought it would work if mapped to a real table and retrieved via LINQ and Entities are also supposed to be retrievable using FromRawSql(...); can anybody please explain what I am doing wrong and/or missing.

I don't expect this to make any difference, but the underlying database being used is SQL2014.

EDIT #1:

I Have just discovered that another `FromSqlRaw` method call within the same context also now fails when the `DbSet<TestResult> TestItems {get; set;}` is included within the DbContext.

This `FromSqlRaw` call worked previously and works again if I comment out the `DbSet<TestResult> TestItems {get; set;}` which make me think this is an issue with the configuration of the TestResult and or TestResultManifest classes?

EDIT #2:

I have tried flattening the result class...

```
public class TestResult2
{

    public Int32 Manifest_ManifestID { get; set; }

    public Int32 TransportJobID { get; set; }

}
```

If I now use the same `FromSqlRaw` to call the same stored procedure (though with the result type changed to `TestResult2` of course), this works. It therefore has to be something to do with the configuration of the [Owned] entity.

EDIT #3

Following the advice from @ivan-stoev, I tried changing the model as follows since the TransportJobID property could be made unique...

```
public class TestResult
{

    public TestResultManifest Manifest { get; set; } = new TestResultManifest();

    [Key]
    public Int32 TransportJobID { get; set; }

}

[Owned]
public class TestResultManifest
{

    public Int32 ManifestID { get; set; }

}
```

This instead resulted in a new exception...

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.
```

As a result, I then tried...

```
var e = TestItems.FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE [dbo].[SelectTestItems]").AsEnumerable();
```

And this too resulted in the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception (as any unhandled NRE) is of course misleading and hides the actual issue, which is that you are hitting some of the EF Core [Keyless entity limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#keyless-entity-types-characteristics). The main reason is that they

> Cannot have a key defined.

thus cannot serve as principal of a relationship (which is what the owner to owned is), hence (note the second bullet):

> Only support a subset of navigation mapping capabilities, specifically:
>
> - They may never act as the principal end of a relationship.
> - They may not have navigations to owned entities
> - They can only contain reference navigation properties pointing to regular entities.
> - Entities cannot contain navigation properties to keyless entity types.

You have to resolve that at model level, otherwise will get the aforementioned exception anytime you try do *something* with the context (the moment when the model is lazily initialized because it's needed for query or CUD operation).

Comment: Ok, so I tried setting TransportJobID as [Key] and removed the [Keyless] attribute; this still does not work as I now get "System.InvalidOperationException: ''FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.'". Tried calling AsEnumerable, but this resulted in the same Exception.

Comment: Yeah, that's another issue (you know, solve one, get another) - cannot compose over SP (at least from SqlServer), you need TVF or view for that, I have other post(s) regarding that. And since owned entities are auto-loaded, not sure you can even combine raw SQL with owned entities (have to check that). But that's separate issue and needs separate question - SO rules demand single concrete issue per post, that's why here I'm just showing the reason of the concrete issue explained in the question, and not trying to solve the whole.

Comment: The first thing to solve is to find and map something unique as key for `TestResult`. Then we have to see what to do with owned member and/or SP.

Comment: I have mapped TransportJobID as a unique key but it does not resolve the problem. I am currently trying to get something working with a TVF instead of an SP...

Comment: Having mapped TransportJobID as a unique key I am working with a TVF instead of an SP, but when I try to "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[_SelectTestItems2]()" it tries to join to a non existing "TestItems" table.

Comment: I did some tests too, so looks like currently there is no way to make this thing with owned entity work. Consider using "flat" (no owned members) `TestResult` class, in which case it can be keyless as originally.

Comment: Thanks for trying; I too have come to the same conclusion - perhaps in an upcoming version this might be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with dotnet core 5.0 and 6.0 and I solved it like this:

Install the nuget package System.Linq.Async depending of you dotnet version https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async

and then in your query you would be able to add the .ToAsyncEnumerable()

This a example in case you use async method:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductTableView>> GetProduct(Pagination pagination, string identifier)
    {

        var ListProductsTable = await _context.ModelView
                                       .FromSqlRaw("GetProductByIdentifier {0}", identifier)
                                       .ToAsyncEnumerable()
                                       .Select(a => new ProductTableView
                                       {
                                           ID = a.ID,
                                           Guid = a.Guid,
                                           Guid_Product_Category = a.Guid_Product_Category,
                                           Guid_Currency = a.Guid_Currency,
                                           NameProduct = a.NameProduct,
                                       }).ToListAsync();

        return ListProductsTable;
    }
```

In case you don't use the async method, you haven't need to add the above nuget package:

```
        public Task<IEnumerable<ProductTableView>> GetProduct(Pagination pagination, string identifier)
    {

        var ListProductsTable = _context.ModelView
                                       .FromSqlRaw("GetProductByIdentifier {0}", identifier)
                                       .AsEnumerable()
                                       .Select(a => new ProductTableView
                                       {
                                           ID = a.ID,
                                           Guid = a.Guid,
                                           Guid_Product_Category = a.Guid_Product_Category,
                                           Guid_Currency = a.Guid_Currency,
                                           NameProduct = a.NameProduct,
                                       }).ToList();

        return ListProductsTable;
    }
```

Comment: Would you still hit the same problem if you defined the owned navigation as required? I've seen how the query compiler generates a join to copy with all-null owned types...